# Can Systemd-free Artix Linux install packages from parent Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, compatibility, openrc

I want to install the Systemd-free [Artix Linux](https://artixlinux.org/), but noticed on [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=artix) that it misses many packages. Being an Arch based distribution, is it possible to install packages directly from Arch repository? May the fact that the two use two different init systems (OpenRC vs Systemd) be a problem?

Comment: I suspect it depends greatly on the package. Most of the packages that run on boot are going to try to install systemd unit files. And they will. But with no systemd, those unit files are useless. You'll probably end up having to create init scripts for your services by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Artix; however it says on their Wikipedia page:

> Artix Linux has its own repos but most packages without systemd
>   dependencies from Arch Linux repos and the Arch User Repository (AUR)
>   can also be used.

For packages that do rely on systemd, they would need to provide replacement packages that can work with OpenRC (or whichever alternative init system you want to use). Note that this applies mostly to daemon packages, which run in the background and provide a service, which need to be started on boot by the init system.

Personally, I use [Parabola](https://www.parabola.nu/), which is a libre distro that is also based on Arch. They support OpenRC and have a [nonsystemd] repository that contains replacement pacakages that work with OpenRC.

If it were me, I would post on the Artix forum, to see if they have something similar and verify if they have versions of the packages you want that work with OpenRC.